# Updating collection in Firebase returns error "found nil while unwrapping optional value"?

Tags: swift, database, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making this app where the idea is that you create a profile, add your dogs, and then update a timer on them (when they last ate, took a walk, etc). I'm having some issues with Firebase though. I managed to have the user add dogs to their account, but now that I'm trying to update some values on a certain dog the app crashes with a "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" which seems to be due to Firebase. My Database contains the user, their dogs and a collection of the dogs values, such as firstTimer. When I try to update this value with the setData() method it just keeps crashing and nothing shows in my database. i've also tried to update values individually but to no avail. Please tell me if I'm going about this the wrong way and if there's some other approach to try, thanks!

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import UIKit

//DogViewController
class MyDogViewController: UIViewController {

    var db: Firestore!
    var auth: Auth!
    var storage: Storage!
    var thisDog: DogEntry?
    var dogRef: DocumentReference!     

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        thisDog?.firstTimer = (formattedDate)

            if let dog = thisDog?.toAny() {
                print("Let")
                //THE PROGRAM PRINTS LET
                dogRef.setData(dog)
                //BUT CRASHES HERE
            }
            else {
                print("Error")
            }
        }
    }
}

//Dog Modal Class
class DogEntry {

    var name: String
    var image: String
    var firstTimer: String
    var secondTimer: String
    var walking: Bool = false
    var walkArray: [String]
    var id: String = ""


    init(name: String, image: String, firstTimer: String, secondTimer: String, walking: Bool, walkArray: [String]) {
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
        self.firstTimer = firstTimer
        self.secondTimer = secondTimer
        self.walking = walking
        self.walkArray = walkArray
   }

    init(snapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot) {
        let snapshotValue = snapshot.data() as [String : Any]
        name = snapshotValue["name"] as! String
        image = snapshotValue["image"] as! String
        firstTimer = snapshotValue["firstTimer"] as! String
        secondTimer = snapshotValue["secondTimer"] as! String
        walking = snapshotValue["walking"] as! Bool
        walkArray = snapshotValue["walkArray"] as! [String]
        id = snapshot.documentID
    }

    func toAny() -> [String: Any] {
        return ["name": name, "image": image, "firstTimer": firstTimer, "secondTimer": secondTimer, "walking": walking, "walkArray": walkArray]
    }
}
```

Comment: So, there is `nil` when when non-`nil` is required (hint: [*search to find out what the error means*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=found+nil+while+unwrapping+optional+value)).. then *work back from the source error line/input and determine why there is an error between expectations and actual value*. This is really not specific to 'databases' or 'firebase' etc.

Comment: I'm aware of the meaning of nil and I know the program crashes because of it. What I don't understand is why the program returns nil at all and what I should do about it. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently we have different ideas of "know"..

Comment: Apparently so. Thanks for your input

Comment: None of your variables are initialized, at least not in the snippet you are giving. You just gave them types. dogRef for example is literally saying, dogRef is of type DocumentReference and should exist. But at no place in your code you are assigning a value to the variable. For sure it’ll crash. Initialize your variable correctly. Something like `dogRef = Firestore.firestore().collection(“the collection”).document(“the document”).....`

Comment: `thisDog?.firstTimer = (formattedDate)` is also going to result in a nil dog as the dog object is not initialized. It's unclear why 'LET' would print as that if statement should fail (it fails in my project). Perhaps there's additional code that's initializing the dog object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dogRef` is an implicitly unwrapped optional. You need to give it a value before you call it.